# After login I just get an orange screen that says Ubuntu 14.04, no sidebar or desktop

Tags: unity

I am an Ubuntu newbie. Ubuntu worked for 2 weeks but one day I installed a few things and then shut down. The next morning when I booted into Ubuntu it let me log in but then it just stayed on an orange screen that said Ubuntu 14.04. The side bar and rest of the desktop never showed up. I waited an hour for and still nothing.

Comment: I just experience this exact same problem today, and I was trying a lot of fixes found in forums, etc. But I had a feeling that it might have something to do with "No Space left in HDD". I was cutting it very tight with my HDD space. So after trying so many things, I decided to try to manually delete some big files I knew exactly where in my folders. So I did ctrl+Alt+F1 and changed directory (cd) to where the file was and deleted them (rm). After that ubuntu booted normally (well I did experiment with "clean" in Recovery mode before trying to reboot). If you have Ubuntu live CD/USB handy, I t

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to log in as a guest user and see if it lets you into the desktop. If it does, then you can backtrack the things you have installed or any settings you may have changed.

I recently had the same problem caused by incorrectly adding an environmental variable in my .profile. If you are in fact able to get into the guest account, use the terminal to ssh into your user account and start troubleshooting.

```
ssh my-user@localhost
```

Good Luck